# Keen IO Dashboards JSON import/export

Tags: keen-io

Is there anything in Keen IO dashboards that makes it easy to import/export dashboards as JSON?
I've looked at example layouts, but I don't see a trace of JSON.

Comment: That's a very cool idea. If you have some ideas on how this might work, either as a standalone app or module, I'd love to hear it! give me a shout at dustin@keen.io

Answer (score 0):

Not that I am aware of right now, but that would be cool to have. Dashboards is under active development, so if you open an issue or PR it will definitely be welcomed.